# Easy way to transpose this data output from tableau?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data export from tableau into excel. it looks like this:

[image]

Now I'd like to convert column B values into their own column headers instead of it repeating over and over like you see. I'd like to convert the yellow highlighted table into this blue highlighted table to the right:

[image]

Unsure if this is a simple feature in excel or if VBA is necessary? I used to know how to do this in VBA, but I haven't even touched the IDE for nearly 3 years. maybe this question has been asked before?

Comment: Its a job for the `Power Query`

Answer (score 1):

Simple VBA pivot:

```vb
Sub DoPivot()
    Const ROW_COL As Long = 1
    Const COL_COL As Long = 2
    Const VAL_COL As Long = 3
    
    Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr, dict, r As Long, vRow, vCol
    Dim dictRw As Object, dictCol As Object
    Set dictRw = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set dictCol = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngIn = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    arr = rngIn.Value
    Set rngOut = ws.Range("F1")
    
    rngOut.Value = arr(1, ROW_COL)
    For r = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
        vRow = CStr(arr(r, ROW_COL))
        vCol = CStr(arr(r, COL_COL))
        If Not dictRw.exists(vRow) Then  'new row ?
            dictRw.Add vRow, dictRw.Count + 1
            rngOut.Offset(dictRw(vRow)).Value = vRow
        End If
        If Not dictCol.exists(vCol) Then 'new column?
            dictCol.Add vCol, dictCol.Count + 1
            rngOut.Offset(0, dictCol(vCol)).Value = vCol
        End If
        'populate the value (note: not checking to see if the cell already has a value...)
        rngOut.Offset(dictRw(vRow), dictCol(vCol)).Value = arr(r, VAL_COL)
    Next r
End Sub
```